# How to generate thrift classes in UTF-16?

Tags: c++, unicode, thrift

Need to generate thrift classes to work with unicode strings. In old thrift versions there was option `cpp_string_type=utf16`, but last thrift version haven't such option. Is there any possibility to generate thrift with `wstring`?

Answer (score 1):

[There's a `cpp_type` annotation](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl), to be used like this:

```
struct wtf {
    1: list<string>  cpp_type "bar" foo
}
```

generates code that uses `bar` instead of the default type, in this case `vector<std::string>`.

From what I know there was never an option named `cpp_string_type`, but even though I scanned the relevant commits I may still miss something.